# How to visualise and save graph in svg without using .dot file with grapviz?

Tags: c++, qt, graphviz

I have QT project that can create a graph with graphviz. Now I need to save it to .svg file picture without making .dot file. How could I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: What another format do you want to push to it?

Comment: I want to create .svg file from Agraph_t. Usually it makes by this steps: Araph_t -> .dot file -> .svg. But I need to do it like this: Agraph_t -> .svg.